# WSO2 Data Analytics Server with Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, wso2-das

Is there any way to setup Cassandra database as the master data source in WSO2 Data Analytic Server.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 DAS, you can create a HBase datasource by specifying the datasource configuration in the `<DAS_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources/ analytics-datasources.xml` file  as follows.

Check this link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+a+Cassandra+Datasource

Comment: thanx @Soorapadman. Is there any script for Cassandra in wso2 das